# Trouble when wanting to delete a pairing from a list

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I have one piece of my code allows the user to delete a pairing which is already in a list of clues. However when I try running this code, an error comes up and I am unsure on how to solve this...
My code for the bit which deletes the pairing is as shows...

```
def delete_pairing(clues):
    found = True
    #USER INPUTS A LETTER AND SYMBOL
    letter=input("What letter would you like to delete? ").upper
    symbol=input("\nWhat symbol would you like to delete? ")
    #THE LETTER AND SYMBOL THE USER INPUTS BECOMES ONE STRING
    delClue = letter + symbol
    #IF THE delClue exists in clues, it will delete the pairing
    if delClue in clues:
    #CODE FOR REMOVING THE CLUE
        clues.remove(delClue)
    # LETS THE USER KNOW WHAT CLUES HAS BEEN DELETED
        print("\nClue ",(delClue)," has been deleted")
        print("\nYour clues are now...")
        print (clues)
    #If delClue doesn't exist in clues, it will print an error message    
    else:
        print("That clue does not exist  ")
    return clues
```

The outcome should be that if the letter and symbol pairing which the user enters is in the list of clues, then it should be deleted. Otherwise, an error message should occur saying that the letter and symbol pairing the user has entered, doesn't exist in the list of clues....

Error which I am having...

```
    delClue = letter + symbol
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'str'
```

Comment: `upper` is a method, add `()` after it to call it.

Comment: Kasra - I have added it to the end of my question...

Answer (score 1):

As [the comment of Ashwini Chaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963259/trouble-when-wanting-to-delete-a-pairing-from-a-list/25963459#comment40650786_25963259) states, you forgot the `()` at the end of this line

> letter=input("What letter would you like to delete? ").upper

so `letter` is not of type string as you may expect, but a `builtin_function_or_method` instead (namely the [`upper()` method of python's string type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper)). And that's way you cannot concatenate it to another string.